# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 - laraclassified - reviews plugin

Tags: mysql, sql

i have laraclassified script on my website, i tried to install reviews system plugin but i got a sql error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `settings` (`key`, `name`, `description`, `field`, `parent_id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `depth`, `active`) values (reviews, Reviews, Reviews System, , 0, 32, 33, 1, 1))

any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: Fix. In what way? do you want to be able to have duplicate keys? If not then don't send them. And do publish the table definition if you can.

Comment: Fix as in install the plugin in anyway possible

Comment: This a bought product (and I suspect outwith the scope of SO)  have you contacted customer support?

Comment: yes but it seems the problem is in my SQL and not the product it self so they couldn't help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to insert duplicate value to the field that you made primary key field.

Try this instead,

1. Please make the primary key field as integer with auto-increment and don't need to pass the value for that field.

or,

2. Make sure that you are inserting unique value for the primary key field.

Note: each way is different and don't try to implement both at the same time.